# Creating Custom WP Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've hit some sort of stumbling bock here, and I can't find my way over it.

I'm trying to craft a custom WP query that searches for posts by country of origin, selecting multiple countries at once.

I have a table that maps countries to regions, so the initial query will search for the selected region, and return all of the countries in that region as an array. For example, if you select Africa, it will return an array of countries within Africa.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['region'])){
     $region = $_REQUEST['region'];

    $regionresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_regions WHERE region='$region'") or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($regionresult);

    if (!$regionresult) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }
} else {
     $region = NULL;
}
```

That part works.

Now, I want to use the returning array to search my WP posts for any that originated from any of the countries in the array. This is the part I can't get to work:

```
$country_search = array(mysql_fetch_array($regionresult));
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => '$country_search',
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'category' => 'Gallery'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I get no results back. In fact, if include `echo "$args";`, what I get back is simply the word "Array." I also only want it to return results from a specific category.

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something simple. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

ty

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($args)` instead of `echo $args`?

Comment: That returns this: "Array ( [posts_per_page] => -1 [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => Country [value] => $country_search [compare] => IN ) ) )"

Comment: `'value' => '$country_search'`should be `'value' => $country_search` without quotes.

Comment: That yields me this:`Array ([posts_per_page] =&gt; -1 [meta_query] =&gt; Array([0] =&gt; Array([meta_key] =&gt; Country [meta_value] =&gt; Array ([0] =&gt; Array([0] =&gt; 4 [id] =&gt; 4
                                    [1] =&gt; Algeria
                                    [country] =&gt; Algeria
                                    [2] =&gt; AF
                                    [region] =&gt; AF
                                )
                        )
                    [compare] =&gt; IN
                )
        )
)`

Comment: Try to `print_r($country_search)` to see the array.

Comment: That yields me this, and also only for one country. It should be returning 49 countries: `Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; 4
            [id] =&gt; 4
            [1] =&gt; Algeria
            [country] =&gt; Algeria
            [2] =&gt; AF
            [region] =&gt; AF
        )

)`

Comment: See what happens if you change `$country_search = array(mysql_fetch_array($regionresult));` to `$country_search = mysql_fetch_array($regionresult);`

Comment: Here is where I am right now: http://www.morepositive.com/gallery-test/?region=AF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the problem was that there were two array objects, and that this:

```
$country_search = array(mysql_fetch_array($regionresult));
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => '$country_search',
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Should have been this:

```
$country_search = array(mysql_fetch_array($regionresult));
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => $country_search,
            'compare' => 'IN',
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But then, instead of returning no posts, it returned all of them. Grumble!

It tured out to be a combination of issues:

1. Instead of imploding the `$country_search_array`, it needs to be
   added as is to the query.
2. Since it's an array, we can't use the `'='` for the compare value. It needs to be `'IN'`

I couldn't have figured it out without the assistance I received here. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
'value' => $country_search,
```

instead of

```
'value' => '$country_search',
```

without the quotes?

Comment: Yes, I kept switching back and forth. Here's where I am right now:http://www.morepositive.com/gallery-test/?region=AF